# how to convert lower case character to upper case?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

```
unichar c;

c = [myString characterAtIndex:0];

unichar catchcar = [c lowercaseString];
```

error : invalid reciever type unicar.

I know `lowercaseString` is used to covert String not character. Is there any solution?

Comment: why don't you just make the string lowerCase before retrieving the character from it?

Comment: @Ashraf, I did, and it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could do the following:

```
unichar catchcar = [[myString lowercaseString] characterAtIndex: 0];
```

If you have a a character only, do the following:

```
// given unichar c

unichar catchcar = [[[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] lowercaseString] characterAtIndex: 0];
```

Comment: fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: catchar ofType: @"txt"]; is throwing an error. I am passing catchar to filename.

Comment: @user426795 - Why are you trying to pass a unichar to a method that takes an NSString?  Just use an NSString in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution for converting case on a single character is to just use the C functions `tolower` and `toupper`. Using the code example from the question and rewriting that would give this for conversion to lowercase:

```
#import <ctype.h>

unichar catchcar = tolower([myString characterAtIndex:0]);
```

No need to do anything complicated with the NSString API. And no need to make the whole string lowercase first either.

Hope this helps,

Erik

Answer (score 1):

```
unichar c = [[myString lowercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];
```

Try this.