# unichar characterAtIndex with specific characters

Tags: ios, objective-c

i use following simple method to show each letter/character from my `NSString`, and to count if my `NSString` has less than 14 letters, then show the rest letters from `Unichar` array, to make total of 14 letters.

Here is a sample code:

```
NSString *str = @"HELLO";

//unichar chrs [14] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // this works great, shows English chars

unichar chrs [14] ={L'б', L'в', L'г',L'д',L'ж',L'з',L'к',L'л',L'м',L'н',L'п',L'р',L'с',L'т'}; // doesnt work


for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    int index = (arc4random() % 14);
    while (chrs[index] != 0)
    {
        index = (arc4random() % 14);
    }
    chrs[index] = [str characterAtIndex: i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    if (chrs[i] == 0) chrs[i] = (arc4random() % 26) + 65;
}


for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {


    NSLog(@"%C", chrs[i]);
}
```

As you can see, commented line works. But my problem is there, **unichar chrs** which includes specific Russian letters.

What I do wrong? Why first **unichar chrs** which is commented works, but this one with cyrillic declared letters doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: Why would the `while (chrs[index] != 0)` ever terminate when none of the 14 choices is zero?

Comment: Can you better explain what your goal is here? Can you show sample output you wish to achieve?

Comment: And please stop tagging with `xcode` unless the question actually is about Xcode.

Comment: oh, yes.. this will show just letters from my NSString, if there are less letters then 14, will show extra random letters from unichar array. It's gonna be used this code to create a game like 4 pics 1 word. I use this code, and works great with english letters/words. but now, i want to make it able to use russian letters also, so.. i have to fix this issue. Why is not showing, even doesn't launch the app when i try to use unichar array with russian declared letters. Thanks

Comment: @RaduRomanov If your start-up loop hits the `while` loop, your app will never start, because the loop is infinite as long as there aren't zeros in the `chars` array.

Comment: @RaduRomanov Your goal is still somewhat unclear. I see you want to end up with 14 characters. Do you want these 14 characters to first be randomly populated with characters from `str` and then fill in any remaining slots with random characters from `chrs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want (but I'm not 100% sure of your goal):

```
NSString *str = @"HELLO";
unichar result[14] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
// "chrs" can have any number of letters as needed
unichar chrs[14] = {L'б', L'в', L'г',L'д',L'ж',L'з',L'к',L'л',L'м',L'н',L'п',L'р',L'с',L'т'};    

int resultLen = sizeof(result) / sizeof(unichar);
int chrsLen = sizeof(chrs) / sizeof(unichar);
// Scatter the letters from "str" through "result"
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    int index;
    do {
        index = arc4random_uniform(resultLen);
    } while (result[index] != 0);

    result[index] = [str characterAtIndex:i];
}

// Fill in the remaining open spots in "result" with random letters from "chrs"
for (int i = 0; i < resultLen; i++) {
    if (result[i] == 0) {
        result[i] = chrs[arc4random_uniform(chrsLen)];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < resultLen; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%C", result[i]);
}
```

There is one flaw with this solution. It is quite possible that the same character from `chrs` can be used more than once to fill in the extra spots in `result`. More logic is needed if this is a problem.

Comment: There was one typo - I forgot the closing curly brace before the `while` statement. I just tested this code and it works just fine.

Comment: great. And the last questions, please. a easy method to convert all unichar chrs from lower to uppercase? thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567624/how-to-convert-lower-case-character-to-upper-case

Comment: I'm so happy, and thankful to you. Thank you so much. You really helped me today. Thanks.